# Use Lightstreamer with IG Index API

Tags: python, python-3.x, lightstreamer

I am trying to use the streaming API from IG Index their documentation is [here](https://labs.ig.com/streaming-api-guide). The Api requires the light streamer client to be included in the app. So I have used [this](https://pypi.org/project/lightstreamer-client/) version and added it to my project.
I have created a function which connects to the server. (I believe)

```py
def connect_light_stream_client():
    if cst == None or xt == None:
        create_session()
    global client
    client = lsc.LightstreamerClient(lightstreamer_username=stream_ident,
                                     lightstreamer_password=stream_password,
                                     lightstreamer_url=light_stream_server)

    try:
        client.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to connect to Lightstreamer Server")
        return
```

Then I call a second function which should fetch a stream of stock data printing the results after each tick.

```py
def listner(item_info):
    print(item_info)

def light_stream_chart_tick():
    sub = lsc.LightstreamerSubscription(mode="DISTINCT", items={"CHART:CS.D.XRPUSD.TODAY.IP:TICK"},
                                        fields={"BID"})
    sub.addlistener(listner)
    sub_key = client.subscribe(sub)
    print(sub_key)
```

The print at the end produces an output of 1. I get nothing from the listener. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong:

1. You must wait for the subscription request to respond with any
   updates. In your code, execution ends before any ticks are received. I put the code from `light_stream_chart_tick()` into the connect method, with a request for input as a wait
2. The `items` and `fields` parameters need to be lists not dicts
3. The Ripple epic is offline (at least when I tried) - I have substituted Bitcoin

```py
def connect_light_stream_client():
    if cst == None or xt == None:
        create_session()
    global client
    client = lsc.LightstreamerClient(lightstreamer_username=stream_ident,
                                     lightstreamer_password=stream_password,
                                     lightstreamer_url=light_stream_server)

    try:
        client.connect()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Unable to connect to Lightstreamer Server")
        return

    sub = lsc.LightstreamerSubscription(
        mode="DISTINCT", 
        items=["CHART:CS.D.BITCOIN.TODAY.IP:TICK"],
        fields=["BID"]
    )
    sub.addlistener(listner)
    sub_key = client.subscribe(sub)
    print(sub_key)

    input("{0:-^80}\n".format("Hit CR to unsubscribe and disconnect"))
    client.disconnect()


def listner(item_info):
    print(item_info)
```

There's a python project [here](https://github.com/ig-python/ig-markets-api-python-library) that makes it a bit easier to interact with the IG APIs, and there's a
streaming sample included. The project is up to date and actively maintained.

*Full disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the project*